# How to display JSON data using a Ruby (Rails) method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm using the [RapLeaf](https://www.rapleaf.com) API in a Rails app and when I call a RapLeaf record I get a response in JSON. How can I display JSON data using a Ruby method?

Here is the **controller**:

```
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
@api = RapleafApi::Api.new('<MY_SECRET_API_KEY>')
```

Here is the **view**:

```
%td
  = @api.query_by_email(@user.email)
```

Here is what it looks like when rendered in the page:

{"gender"=>"Male"}

I want to be able to call the gender this way

```
%td
  = @api.query_by_email(@user.email).gender
```

But I get an **undefined method `gender' for {"gender"=>"Male"}:Hash**

What sort of method do I need to create to call gender using `.gender`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that output data is a Ruby hash and not JSON. I've got to get my terminology strait.